# spring boot Filter selected columns from from data table connected by a foreign key using data JPA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I Have two tables as

1. student (student_id(primary key), student_index(unique key), student_name, student_batch, student_department, student_age)
2. exam_result_sem_one (result_id, subject_one, subject_two, subject_three, subject_4, fk_student_id)

then I want to get all data from exam_result_sem_one by student_index with the values of student_index and student_name from student table.

I want to do this using spring data JPA instead of using native query. I hopefully waiting for an answer.